# Outputting PHP string into a JS file causes syntax error

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to output a string into a JS file using PHP. Here's the PHP code

```
$embedded_form_js = "document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        var parts = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
        var $_GET = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            var temp = parts[i].split('=');
            $_GET[decodeURIComponent(temp[0])] = decodeURIComponent(temp[1]);
        }


        var ref = $_GET['ref'];

        if (ref === 'undefined')
        {
            ref = 0;
        }

}, false);";
```

I'm trying to write a JS file like so

```
$fp = fopen("FOLDER/FILE.js", 'w');
fwrite($fp, $embedded_form_js);
fclose($fp);
```

The problem is that when I try to write the JS file, this error happens.

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ']'
```

This is in reference to the line:

```
$_GET[decodeURIComponent(temp[0])] = decodeURIComponent(temp[1]);
```

How can I remedy this?

Comment: I don't not see your addEventListener( closing bracket in the JS, or for that matter the closing } of the function

Comment: what's in `$_GET['ref']`?

Comment: @AndrewKillen Whoops. I truncated the code for StackOverflow. The closing bracket is there in my full code.

Comment: @DanielA.White $_GET['ref'] is a variable in the URL

Comment: @kevinkt i know that, but what is its value?

Comment: Because of when jour code is generated then this code looks like var $_GET = {}; after generated var ={};

Comment: you can't mix and match the javascript and php like that on that line.

Comment: which line do you get the error at?

Comment: @kevinkt : Yes Danial is right. you can't mix Js and php. better to concat the data in parts.

Comment: @prakashtank but none of the above is php `$_GET` here is just a javascript variable.

Comment: Since you're using double quotes to surround your javascript, it may be actually parsing the php `$_GET` variable, which could be causing your issues.

Comment: Man, just take the entire outputted JS code and check it in any JS IDE, it will highlight the error for you

Comment: If you want to output the parameters from php, why don't just `echo 'var params = ' . json_encode($_GET, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) . ';';` (or something similar)? or just figure the conditions on the server side and just output `echo 'var ref = ' . (empty($_GET['ref']) ? '0' : $_GET['ref']) . ';';`

Comment: After concatenating the string into parts, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Nowdocs as it is single-quoted and won't try to interpret the $_GET

```
$embedded_form_js = <<<'EOS'
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        var parts = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
        var $_GET = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            var temp = parts[i].split('=');
            $_GET[decodeURIComponent(temp[0])] = decodeURIComponent(temp[1]);
        }


        var ref = $_GET['ref'];

        if (ref === 'undefined')
        {
            ref = 0;
        }

}, false);
EOS;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc